# Using datepicker without external files

Tags: jsp, datepicker

Is it possible that I want to add the date picker element in my jsp file without using any external files like jQuery and Dojo. Thanks.

Comment: yes you can but it would be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: If you can use HTML5 (and your users use Chrome, Opera, or Safari), then use `<input type="date" ... />`. See http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-date.php